# Where should I redirect (removed) phishing pages

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, security

I was unfortunately the victim of a PHP exploit. Looking through my webserver logs, people are still attempting to reach the URL used in the phish. I want to redirect them to a site that will educate these people on what phishing is.

My question: Is there a (generic / vendor-neutral) phishing education website that you suggest I send them to with a 301 redirect? (I assume a 301 is the best option.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is a good landing page to drop people on. It's here:

http://education.apwg.org/r/en/index.htm

It's designed to educate users, in a helpful way.

Comment: Better use http://education.apwg.org/r/ so visitors get the page in their language.

Answer (score 0):

I think a 301 to a useful page will be a bit confusing. I would send them to a generic page explaining that their URL came from phishing and then link to [this article on the BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/webwise/guides/about-spoofing). It is unhelpfully titled "spoofing" but uses the word phishing further down.